# Javascript file modifying an html file that it is not called from? Jquery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, selector

Is its possible to have a javascript file that is aware of two different HTML files? And how would I do this?

I would like to be able to have two pages. index.html and pictures.html. I have an index.js that changes the display properties of index.html  (it puts data based on people into tables and makes it look nice). I would like this current index.js file also to be able to edit the pictures.html file and change information there. index.html would link to pictures.html to display pictures of a person (based on the persons name I have them saved smith1.jpg, smith2.jpg, reagan2.jpg, ect). Is there anyway that this javascript file could get DOM elements based on their id or class of the second file (pictures.html) even though it "lives in" index.html? When i say lives in it is called at the top of the index.html page.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script can access elements on another page if it was loaded in some way of connection.

For example, if you make a popup using `var popup = window.open()`, the return value will contain a reference to the opened popup and this allows access to elements within the popup. E.g. `popup.document.getElementById('something')`. Pages loaded within frames, iframes and such have similar ways of access.

So yes, if your page loads the second page its script can work there as well. I suggest avoiding this beyond opening and closing popups from a script though; a script should stay inside the box of its page and if it needs to do larger operations on another page, that usually means that you need to change your code architecture a bit.

Comment: Agreed... Technically true (+1). But couldn't we say that those are not first-class pages... and shouldn't be the first choice in patterns?

Comment: It's a horrendous thing but it works. I haven't found any application for it besides closing a popup from the main script.

Comment: nice hack I used this for this current problem (due to time constraints), but in the future I definitely should use some sort of server side scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to explore server-side programming to accomplish your goal.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

...Or you could write a client-side application in which "pages" are separate views of one actual page or are generated from backing data structures.  If you want persistance of what is created/edited, you'll still need server-side programming.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, theres no way to do this all client side then?

Comment: Not without some flavor of server-side component. Do you have any experience with server-side languages?

Comment: Just a bit of Ruby on rails, I think I am going to look into server side javascript that always interested me I just never got around to exploring it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html5 (group of technologies) postmessage api as well.. This allows you to send messages to another page, and in that page you define an event handler that knows how to handle the message.

This also works across domains.

Here is a blog with an example I just randomly found via google:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/

Comment: Exciting new feature of HTML5... but be sure that you know your userbase and that their browsers are capable. Choosing this solution adds dependencies on the user's browser capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible on the client side if editing the actual HTML file is your goal. If getting pictures to show up depending on stuff a user does on another page is all you care about then there are lots of options.

- You can pass small sets of data like stuff the user entered into tables via cookies for accessing the right sets of image files in a pre-established scheme. This would actually persist until a user cleared out cookies.
- You could wrap both pages in same-domain iframe elements with the parent element containing just the JS. This would allow you to persist data between pages and react to iframe load events but like everything in client-side JS, it's all gone when you reload the page.
- Newer browsers have working file access objects that aren't total security nightmares. These are new and non-standard enough that it would take some doing to make it work for multiple browsers. This could be used to save files containing info that the user would probably have to be prompted to upload when they return to the site.
- If the data's not sensitive you could get creative and use another service to stash collections of data. Use a twitter API to tweet data to some publicly visible page of a twitter account (check the Terms of Service if you're doing anything more than an isolated class project here). Then do an Ajax get request on whatever URL it's publicly visible at and parse the HTML for your twitter data.

Other stuff I'd look into: dataURIs, html5 local storage.

Note: None of these are approaches I would seriously consider for a professional site where the data was expected to be persistent or in any way secure regardless of where a user accesses it from.